# FFMPEG watermark text / photo transparent opacity problem

Tags: ffmpeg, transparency, opacity, watermark

I've came across two problems.

1. I'm trying to resize and set the opacity/transparency of a watermark, and I can't seem to do it in one command line.

command to rescale but not set transparency:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "[1]scale=iw*0.1:-1[wm];[0][wm]overlay=x=15:y=10" output.mp4
```

2. Trying to set transparency of text but leave the border of the text greyish.

command to resize text and set border, but could not set transparency:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -filter_complex "drawtext=fontfile=wryh.ttf:text='sample':x=20:y=15:fontcolor=white@1:fontsize=15:fontcolor=white:bordercolor=black:borderw=0.51" output.mp4
```

Comment: Seems to have solved the first problem -- scaling and watermark being transparent: 
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "[1]format=rgba,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.7,scale=iw*0.1:-1[logo];[0][logo]overlay=15:10:format=auto,format=yuv420p" -c:a copy video.mp4

Answer (score 1):

Combined command:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "[1]format=rgba,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.7,scale=iw*0.1:-1[logo];[0][logo]overlay=15:10:format=auto,drawtext=fontfile=wryh.ttf:text='sample':x=20:y=15:fontcolor=white@1:fontsize=15:fontcolor=white:bordercolor=black:borderw=0.51,format=yuv420p" -c:a copy video.mp4
```